# oracle sql: Persons older than the average age of persons with the same nationality

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list all persons who are older than the average age of persons with the same nationality. There are three tables involved: person, passport, and country. This is what i have so far:

```
select round(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) as age, country.name, person.name, person.surname
from person
join passport on person.pid= passport.pid
join country on passport.cid= country.cid
where round(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) > 
(select avg(round(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12))
from person join passport on person.pid= passport.pid
join country on passport.cid= country.cid);
```

For some reason, I get  undesired results which are less than the average age of persons. The select statement for the average age of people of the same nationality is:

```
SELECT  avg(round(months_between(sysdate, dateofbirth) / 12)) as age, country.name  
from person
join passport on person.personid = passport.personid
join country on passport.countryid = country.countryid
group by country.name;
```

I used this without the *group by* clause within my subselect above. This works fine but the query does not produce the results correctly with only the persons whose age is greater than the average age.

Comment: Hint;  You have too many joins in the subquery.  It should be correlated with the outer query.

Comment: I dropped all the joins from the _subselect_ but still the undesired results appear in output. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for an analytic function:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (select round(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) as age,               
               country.name country_name,
               person.name person_first_name, 
               person.surname person_last_name,
               avg(round(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12)) 
                    over (partition by country.name ) avg_for_country
          from person
                join passport on person.pid = passport.pid
                join country on passport.cid = country.cid
       )
 WHERE age > avg_for_country
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there's an error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=923] when executing this code. @Matthew McPeak

Comment: It only seems a typo: `partition by ( country.name )` --> `OVER (PARTITION BY country.name)`

Comment: Thank you! Works very well!